# Security issues for Minecraft server on Time Capsule

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a public Minecraft server (public ip) from my Time Capsule.
Could someone get disk access if they figured out the password, or knew my IP and I had a Time Capsule?

The server is running in a virtual Ubuntu machine. I gave out the public ip for the virtual machine.

My questions are:
If they found out the password would they be able to access the virtual machine or my computer?

Would it be more secure if I used Mineos or Ubuntu server?

I heard that hosting a Minecraft server is super secure from the official Minecraft forum.
Is that true?

Comment: How does this related to your earlier question on the same topic - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27720/self-host-a-minecraft-server-with-high-security

Comment: Because a router isn't subject to the same security issues a time capsule is, because it is connected to external drives and has an internal harddisk.  A "regular" router is very basic and doesn't include these features.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about general computer configuration, not gaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time Capsules are generally only accessible if you are connected to them as a router, and then mount it as a shared drive (by typing in the password you've set for the drive).

However, if you set up your Time Machine to be accessible over the web (like the instructions [here](http://forums.dealmac.com/read.php?4,2800627)), there is of course the possibility that someone will brute force your Time Machine's drive's password and be able to mount it.

The OS your server is running is irrelevant to to security of your Time Capsule – if you can mount it over the web, you have security vulnerabilities.

Regarding your point about the Minecraft Forums, they don't offer Minecraft server hosting. They simply allow you to make a thread about your server to advertise it.

Comment: I'm only opening port 25565, which shouldn't be an issue because their port is 56124

Comment: Link in answer is dead.