# How do I play with my friend alone on a private server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I host my own Minecraft server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server)

Me and my friend want to join a server together with no other people, do you now how we can do that? Cause I have tried joining multiplayer servers, but other people are always there.

Comment: The question [How can I host my own Minecraft server?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server) should contain the information you want. Also related: [Self-host a minecraft server with high security](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27720/88) (Disclaimer: I posted an answer to the latter...)

Comment: You can also have a look at Minecraft wiki's [Server](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server) page . They also have a [link to the Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewforum.php?f=1027) where you can find online hosts that you don't have to run on your own PCs but still are yours to command (but these cost money of course)

Comment: I think I improved the title?